# I can't seem to get this simple code to work

Tags: javascript, html

This is meant to load an image below the buttons. Each button loads the same image, but with different attributes. Like color, in this example.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
        $("#area").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' alt='description' />");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button data-rel="http://i.imgur.com/icb4onK.jpg">Blue</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button data-rel="http://i.imgur.com/3mSS06v.jpg">Red</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button data-rel="http://i.imgur.com/Su3Rtoy.jpg">Green</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="area"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This works here: https://jsfiddle.net/x3QdU/53/

But when I save a Microsoft Notepad file as test.html (I did select all file types) It will only load the buttons. The buttons do nothing. I don't know if it's an issue in how I added the JavaScript, or if maybe it's my browser. I'm using Google Chrome.

I would also like to know if this code will work in an HTML app on a website.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use jQuery functions without including jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't including jQuery (which is a good thing, because jQuery is not needed here!)

You can implement the same without jQuery like so:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Create the image
    var img = new Image();
    // And put it in the document
    document.getElementById('area').appendChild(img);

    // Find all the buttons in the document...
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'), function(button) {
        // Add a click handler on each
        button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            // To change the src of the image
            img.src = this.dataset.rel;
        });
    });
});
```

**[Here's an example for it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/c28rq0p8/)**

If you're insisting on using jQuery, have a look at any of the other answers, they tell you how to include jQuery in your document.

The reason it works in your jsFiddle is because you've included it there in the settings

[image: jQuery is included]

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the jQuery library in your code.

Add this before your `<script>` tag in your `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you prefer a local copy of jQuery, download it from https://jquery.org/ and add it to your project. Then use the following code:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to include jQuery before your script. JSFiddle does that for you but on your standalone version you should do it yourself.

Put this before your own script-tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or import jQuery from your own location

Answer (score 1):

You have to add jquery library as follows, which is present in jsfiddle sample.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```